# Make "Unknown Option" on any command after installing Adroid-x86 build tools

Tags: 18.04, kernel, compiling, android, android-sdk

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 in vMware ESXi and have been building kernels to test on a tablet. I've had no issues with configuring or compiling up to this point.
Now I'm setting up a build environment for Android-x86. Everything is fine through installing the extra cross-compile packages and dependencies, initializing the repo and syncing it.
The next step is to setup the build environment with

```
. build/envsetup.sh
```

which seems to run fine and gives the expected output.
Next you set up the config with "lunch"

```
$ lunch android_x86_64-userdebug
```

and that also runs fine with no errors and creates the config.

Next step is to run make, directing the output to the build directory and getting the configuration menu

```
make -C kernel O=$OUT/obj/kernel ARCH=x86 menuconfig
```

and that's when it happens.

```
Unknown option: -C
```

From this point NO option in make will work unless I use sudo or su.
make -v says "unknown option". Same with ANY option both long and short format. 
It's doing something that completely screws the ability of the user account to run make without sudo, and according to all docs you aren't supposed to run make as root.
I've tried this on 2 systems now. Both being able to run make as a normal user account with no issues UNTIL running the envsetup.sh script. After that no dice.
I can't seem to find anything like this error on any other discussions and could really use some suggestions on how to get access to make again without being root.

[EDIT:]
Upon more testing I discovered that running make -v OUTSIDE the android-x86 directory still works, so something is actually wrong inside the directory, but according to docs my understanding is you're supposed to run the build commands at the top of the android-x86 directory tree

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like

```
/usr/bin/make -C kernel O=$OUT/obj/kernel ARCH=x86 menuconfig
```

Comment: Hey, Larry, welcome to the site.  It would be much better to [edit] this answer and explain *why* you're right and how this will help.  Otherwise, this answer is subject to removal.  Thanks!